# Is there any IWUF-compliant material of Wushu techniques and forms for reference?

Tags: technique, kung-fu, forms, wushu

I'm looking for a reliable book, website or document that I can use for reference to study each technique specification, and memorize each compulsory Wushu form defined by IWUF. For Changquan and/or Sanshou.

My Wushu teacher recommended the Wushu Dictionary from the website thewushucentre.ca (which is currently down), but it's just a dictionary with images and explanations in french.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My wife got pretty far into contemporary wushu. She had good teachers, but one book she frequently turned to was *Fundamentals of High Performance Wushu: Taolu Jumps and Spins* by Raymond Wu. You can find it on Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-High-Performance-Wushu-Taolu/dp/1430318201](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430318201)

It goes over a lot of the jumping and spinning techniques. The text and drawings should help a lot, especially when you just can't quite get something. I found it very helpful for trying to understand the butterfly. Even though I knew how to do the butterfly, the book showed me how to make it better. And it allowed me to see how to do b-twist, something I had never been taught.

My wife also does adult gymnastics to learn the aerial, back-flip, somersault, front hand-spring, and back hand-spring, amongst other techniques. She attends a class once a week and she goes to "open gym" once a week ("open gym" means you pay a small fee, usually just $5, to use the gym for whatever you want to work on for an hour). While she's at open gym, she uses the foam pit to work on all of her gymnastics techniques plus the butterfly-twist and other wushu techniques.

So she recommends finding a gymnastics gym near you and at least use their open gym to practice dangerous stuff with the foam pit. But you also should think about attending a gymnastics class or taking private lessons once a week. You at least need someone qualified to spot you when you're working on the floor and even on the trampoline (where you can actually break your neck if you do stuff wrong).

Later on, you can work on wushu-izing your gymnastics stuff, once you have the fundamentals understood.

Aside from that, you might want to familiarize yourself with the scoring system, technicals, and compulsory forms. There are many videos on Youtube that do go over them. For example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSyamyooEvE

Type in "IWUF taolu", and you will find a treasure trove of videos covering IWUF techniques. Some are old, but even those can be useful.

Also, the iwuf.org web site has various documents going over tournament rules and so forth. They also have videos going over the rules and showing you the compulsory forms.

I have to say, I'm impressed with IWUF's openness. They put a lot of this material up on the web. With many other wushu and kung-fu organizations, you almost never see this.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE:

You asked for IWUF links, because they weren't working for you? Did you try disabling your script blocker? Sometimes that helps. Otherwise try a different browser. I use Firefox.

At the top of the iwuf.org web site, you should see selections appear as you move your mouse (hover over) the top menu. For example, if you hover over the "News Center", one of the selections will be "Videos". Click that, and you will see this:

http://www.iwuf.org/news_video.asp

They have a number of rules videos there.

They list their Competition Regulations here:

http://www.iwuf.org/regu.asp

The Taolu Rules are here:

http://www.iwuf.org/rule.asp

That links to ".doc" document format stuff. You need either Microsoft Word or Libre Office to view them. For example:
  http://www.iwuf.org/upfile/Rules_of_Taolu(English).doc

Anyway, hope that helps. If you can't figure out why the iwuf.org web site isn't working for you, try a different browser or have a nerdy friend figure out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve! Can you add the links to these IWUF contents that are on their site? I've looked for these materials there and couldn't find any.

Comment: I just added the requested links as an update. See above.

Comment: Thank you, Steve! I just couldn't find the links, guess I was looking for it in the wrong place LOL :D

Answer (score 2):

There are current IWUF text books/dvd available from Kungfudirect.com, the material is written in Chinese however it should cover what you are looking for. Peace, Love, Wushu!