# Wushu: Jumps, Falls, Acrobatics

Tags: training, kung-fu, forms, competition, wushu

I am an adult interested in reaching a personal high level in wushu. I realize that some of the most difficult techniques come in the acrobatics elements. I figure that it would help to get a head start on learning the skills.

Do you have any techniques or can recommend a resource where I can find a list with all of wushu acrobatic techniques.

Thank you

Comment: My answer at the following link goes over some of what you want to know: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/is-there-any-iwuf-compliant-material-of-wushu-techniques-and-forms-for-reference/2888#2888

Comment: Taking basic gymnastics courses is the open door to studying wushu.

Answer (score 2):

The Wudang monastery documentaries I have seen show the monks teaching the young students balancing exercises ie on one leg, as well as landing on the feet when jumping from increasing heights! Also climbing up a pretty high wall. In more general terms balance is a Taiji energy which practice of the forms etcetera should therefore improve. It is also a tenet that when being demonstrated upon by the teacher, a student should seek to always remain on his feet when thrown or whatever. This becomes a highly useful skill in itself.